# How to count records per year using R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a Data frame [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV047.png) that runs from 1931 until 2020, I need to count how many records per year there are and create a table that only shows year and count. I'm trying to loop over a variable (in this case the year) but I'm just getting the table [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgzaD.png) with 1 row of the data of 2020.

```
    for(i in c("2011",
              "2012",
              "2013",
              "2014",
              "2015",
              "2016",
              "2017",
              "2018",
              "2019",
              "2020")){
  
  prueba <- prueba2 %>%
  filter(year == i) %>%
  group_by(year)%>%
  summarise(freq=n())}
```

Comment: You don't need the loop or `filter`.  `group_by` and `summarise` will give you what you need.

Comment: `prueba2 %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(freq=n())` should work.

Comment: In Base you could use `lengths(split(prueba2$year,prueba2$year))`

Answer (score 0):

This will produce a count by year:

```
prueba %>% count(year)
```

Comment: Great that works, thanks!